# Looping through a class and adding each row to a DataTable only adds one row

Tags: c#, class, foreach

I have the following loop in C#:

```
        PayrollItem[] it = GetPayrollItems(xmlResult);

        foreach (var inv in it)
        {
            DataRow row = ResultsTable.NewRow();
            row["EmployeeKey"] = inv.BadgeNo;
            row["StoreKey"] = inv.CostCentre;
            row["EmployeeName"] = inv.EmpName;
            row["DateKey"] = inv.Date;
            row["Incheck"] = inv.In;
            row["Outcheck"] = inv.Out;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inv.BadgeNo {0} i StoreKey {1}", inv.EmpName, inv.CostCentre);
            ResultsTable.Rows.Add(row);
            return ResultsTable;
        }
```

where `xmlResult` is a XML file filled with data from using a SOAP API call, and `GetPayrollItems();` basically loops through said XMLfile and adds values accordingly:

```
    public static PayrollItem[] GetPayrollItems(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        var items = new List<PayrollItem>();

        var node = xmlDoc.LastChild; //SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        if (node != null)
        {
            node = node.FirstChild; //SOAP-ENV:Body
            if (node != null)
            {
                node = node.FirstChild; //ns1:wsdlGetValuesResponse
                if (node != null)
                {
                    node = node.FirstChild;  //return

                    if (node != null)
                    {
                        int count = node.ChildNodes.Count;

                        foreach (XmlNode nodeItem in node.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            PayrollItem item = new PayrollItem();

                            item.EmpName = nodeItem["empName"].InnerText;
                            item.BadgeNo = nodeItem["badgeNo"].InnerText;
                            item.CostCentre = nodeItem["costCentre"].InnerText;
                            item.Date = nodeItem["date"].InnerText;
                            item.In = nodeItem["in"].InnerText;
                            item.Out = nodeItem["out"].InnerText;
                            items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return items.ToArray();
    }
```

where I have defined `PayrollItems` as:

```
   public class PayrollItem 
    {
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string BadgeNo { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string In { get; set; }
        public string Out { get; set; }
        public string CostCentre { get; set; }
    }

    public class PayrollList : List<PayrollItem>
    {
        public void Add(string empName, string badgeNo, string date, string @in, string @out, string costCentre)
        {
            var data = new PayrollItem
                {
                    EmpName = empName,
                    BadgeNo = badgeNo,
                    Date = date,
                    In = @in,
                    Out = @out,
                    CostCentre = costCentre
                };
            this.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

I call the function `GetPayrollItems` from the function `GetPayroll`. This function takes some parameters, of which is the API key of a specific store.

I've noticed that `GetPayrollItems()` function returns sometimes 20 rows of each iteration, i.e. for one store. However, when I inspect the table `ResultsTable` when the program has executed, I noticed that only *one* row is added for each store.

When I tested the loop which adds rows to `ResultsTable` I've noticed that it sometimes have up to 20 rows in an iteration, but still only one row is added to the `ResultsTable`.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Comment: You are returning in the foreach loop. So only getting the first item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the return out of the loop.

```
PayrollItem[] it = GetPayrollItems(xmlResult);

    foreach (var inv in it)
    {
        DataRow row = ResultsTable.NewRow();
        row["EmployeeKey"] = inv.BadgeNo;
        row["StoreKey"] = inv.CostCentre;
        row["EmployeeName"] = inv.EmpName;
        row["DateKey"] = inv.Date;
        row["Incheck"] = inv.In;
        row["Outcheck"] = inv.Out;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inv.BadgeNo {0} i StoreKey {1}", inv.EmpName, inv.CostCentre);
        ResultsTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }

return ResultsTable;
```